# How to run cocos creator's android build in the background

Tags: javascript, java, android, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

Actually i have a poker game developed in Cocos Creator(v2.0.9) using JavaScript. The game uses web socket. So when the android application is in background, web socket also pause due to this the game misses broadcast fired by server. Every time we need to reconnect whenever the app resumes which causes difficulty to the user. And also the actions and scheduler pauses.

So, i want that my app still run in background to maintain the game state.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a poker game too, and we handled this same situation in the following way.

Instead of trying to listen to server messages in background, you could do this, when your app resumes, ask for a packet from server that contains the current state of the game, and all the data that you need to populate your scene. And after you receive that data, process that data, populate your scene and then the normal loop of your game can resume.

Note: After re-connection, make sure your game waits for the sync up data before processing any other data, that you might receive as soon your game connects with the server.